# PrimeFaces - How to add <p:submenu> in <p:toolbargroup>?

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.3.1. I need to use `<p:submenu>` in `<p:toolbarGroup>`. Is there any way to do?

I don't use `<p:menubar>` because there are some problems with menubar. Such as,

- when i want to hover a submenu item, its menuitems disappear before i can click them
- i am using "start" theme and toolbar looks much better than menubar
- there is no "align" option. (i know i can do it by "style" option but usage of align option in toolbarGroup is simpler:)

etc..

So I want to use `<p:toolbar>` but I can't use `<p:submenu>` in `<p:toolbarGroup>`. How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should use p:menubutton and p:menuitem like this:

```
<p:toolbarGroup align="right">
    <'p:menuButton value="Options">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="http://www.primefaces.org" />  
        <p:menuitem value="ShowCase" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase" />  
        <p:menuitem value="TouchFaces" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/touch" />  
    </p:menuButton>  
</p:toolbarGroup>
```

Comment: i know that. i need `<p:submenu>` instead of one of these `<p:menuitem>`.